# Is Magento the right platform to sell individual files/serials?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, product, downloadable

I'm looking to set up a store that sells unique items. I'm looking to sell virtual downloadable items, however, I'd like each item to have a quantity but each item sold to come with a different file to download.

For example, I'm selling serial keys for my product, along with other things.

If a user buys the item, they should be emailed or send a download link to their serial key. However, I DONT want two people to get the same serial.

Would Magento be able to handle this? Or should I look for a different platform (if so, any suggestions?)

Comment: Are you asking if this functionality is available out of the box for a Magento installation ?

Comment: You can achieve this but for this you need total customization. it wont get with default magento.

Comment: Yeah Magento can do that with customisation. Also magento comes with virtual product types already so thats one thing you don't need to worry about.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, everyone! I'll look more into it. I was hoping it would come out of the box since I'm new to Magento so wasn't sure if this is possible or how to add it.